# Como ler um XML com C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Bom sou novo em C# e estou com um dúvida relacionada a ler um XML.

A XML é essa:

```
<ComportamentoPapeis>
<Papel Codigo="PETR4" Nome="PETROBRAS PN" Ibovespa="#" Data="19/06/2015 17:59:59" Abertura="13,31" Minimo="13,10" Maximo="13,44" Medio="13,26" Ultimo="13,15" Oscilacao="-2,15"/>
<Papel Codigo="PETR3" Nome="PETROBRAS ON" Ibovespa="#" Data="19/06/2015 17:55:12" Abertura="14,62" Minimo="14,46" Maximo="14,90" Medio="14,68" Ultimo="14,50" Oscilacao="-2,02"/>
</ComportamentoPapeis>
```

Gostaria de pegar os dados desta xml para gerar um gráfico candlestick.

Comment: Relacionado: [Ler arquivo XML em C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48892/ler-arquivo-xml-em-c)

Comment: Você quer ler e passar para qual formato?

Comment: Então tipo eu quero ler e jogar em um banco então tenho que salvar em váriaveis